# Replacing sealed halogen bulb

Tags: electrical, lighting, bathroom, shower

I'm trying to replace my halogen downlighter in my bathroom. It was installed around 2009 and I'm in the UK. The downlighter is in a waterproof cover because it is directly above the shower. I can't work out how to access the bulb. I can pull the unit down from the ceiling about an inch, and I can twist the bottom of the unit about 1/8 turn, but nothing seems to come apart, and there are no visible screws. I've attached a photo. Can anyone advise on how to proceed? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you push up on the glass, does it move? I had a few like this; they seemed permanently sealed, but was more of an internal gasket and the bulb would push out to replace.

Comment: I'd guess one of two things, both involving "stuck gasket after 7 years next to a hot bulb" - either it needs to go more than 1/8 turn, or, having gone 1/8 turn it needs to be pulled apart (bottom from top) vertically.

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks for the suggestion. I just tried more twisting and pulling, but nothing budges I'm afraid!

Comment: @Roberto thanks for the suggestion. I just tried pushing on the glass but no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Aurora series downlights:

[image]

for example, [here is some catalog](https://cewgroup.co.uk/280-downlighting?p=7).

Judging from photos, their springs are above than that riveted steel, which is BTW might be another spring holding bottom cover (on the catalog many models with same or similar body but with different cover).

Comment: This is a good suggestion, thank you Flanker! I hadn't noticed any spring-loaded clips, as they are shown in your photo, but I will have another look when I'm home later. I presume that if I can release those, I may be able to pull the whole unit out of the ceiling a bit more easily...

Comment: I had another look at the unit, and it is definitely one of these Aurora downlighters. I can see the spring-loaded clips now, but can't access them at all. Too fiddly for me! I think I'll just have to resort to getting an electrician in...